# Problem with ssl comuniction with post request

Tags: node.js, ssl, post

> Hey, I built ssl communication with self certificate. The connection is working, but when I trying to deliver data on the client side with post request in postman or my android client, the body of the request in the server side is empty.
> Here is my nodejs server code below,thankes for help.

```
const express = require('express')
const https = require('https')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')


const app = express()
app.use(express.json())    


app.post('/',(req,res,next)=>
{
    console.log("we got new connection")
    var data =req.body

    res.send(data)
})

const ssl_server = https.createServer(
    {
    key:fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'cert','key.pem')),
    cert:fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'cert','cert.pem'))
    
},app)

ssl_server.listen(3443,console.log("SSl server is online!"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading the `res`ponse body. You should look at the `req`uest.

In any case, there won't probably be much reasonable data to read unless you parse the POST payload somehow; I'd recommend the Express library rather than raw Node.js HTTP bits if you don't want to do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> here is my answer for my question,like AKS said, you need to parse the post request, i add bodyparser to my code and it worked.

```
const express = require('express')
const https = require('https')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))    // <==== parse request body as JSON

app.post('/',(req,res,next)=>
{
    console.log("we got new connection")
    var data =req.body

    res.send(data)
})

const ssl_server = https.createServer(
    {
    key:fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'cert','key.pem')),
    cert:fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'cert','cert.pem'))
    
},app)

ssl_server.listen(3443,console.log("SSl server is online!"))
```